# How can I keep vscode from bringing other apps to the foreground

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use a launch target of edge or chrome, and hit F5 or click launch, vscode will bring others apps to the foreground before (or contemporaneous with) launching.

```
{
    "name": "Launch Edge test",
    "type": "msedge",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "request": "launch"
},
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome test",
    "type": "chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "request": "launch"
},
```

It brings to the foreground what seems to be a seemingly random non-maximized window. It's either sending itself backwards in the z-order or bringing something else forward.

```
System Info:
-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 6.4.3-060403-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #202307110536 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 11 05:43:58 UTC 2023
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
Distribution        : Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, GNOME Shell 42.9
```